# Populate textboxes after selecting a value in a populated list box

Tags: c#, mysql

im trying to populate 3 textboxes from mysql database from list box selection c#.
when i load the page and click query button it populates the listbox then when i pick another value in the list box it auto queries to populate the text boxes but does not fill them in at all.

```
    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string selectedperson = listBox1.GetItemText(listBox1.SelectedItem);
        string query = "Select * from `clients` 
                       WHERE 'client_nickname'='" + selectedperson + "'";

        MySqlConnection conn2 = new MySqlConnection("datasource =" +   
 Properties.Settings.Default.Hostname + " ;
 username = " + Properties.Settings.Default.Username + ";
 password = " + Properties.Settings.Default.Password + "; 
 port = " + Properties.Settings.Default.Port + "; 
 database = " + Properties.Settings.Default.Database);

        conn2.Open();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, conn2);

        if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
        {
            da.Fill(ds);
            textBox1.Text = ds.Tables[8].Rows[2]["client_unique_id"].ToString();
            textBox2.Text = ds.Tables[8].Rows[4]["client_login_name"].ToString();
            textBox3.Text = ds.Tables[8].Rows[5]["client_login_password"].ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: have u checked that u are getting howmany rows in ds.Table?

Comment: yes i have i used the counting system starting from 0. Ie 0=1st row ect. The Table i want is table 8 on the same scale and those 3 rows are the ones i want

Comment: And how many records u r getting in table 8 each time?

Comment: total amount a clients is 137 as of right now

Comment: ok... is that textboxes are inside list box?

Comment: I dont understand the textboxes should be filled after selected value is selected

Comment: The list box is at top then after i select a clients name then the text boxes get populated with their info

Comment: sorry not getting what u are saying

Comment: Ok its a windows form when i press query button on page after it loads it populates the list from the list after i select a clients name its suppose to populate the textboxes automaticly withe the clients info

Comment: have u tried to debug that out? and checked that whether it is going inside if condition or not?

Comment: Yes it runs the query flawlessly but does not retrieve the values to populate the textboxes so im missing something some where and cannot figure it out

Comment: I think i might need a data reader instead of a fill.